# polynomial operator+ function is causing the wrong output or is it print function

Tags: oop, c++17, operator-overloading

this is the output showing :
+2x^0 +0x^1 +0x^2 +0x^3 -5x^4
+0x^0 +0x^1 +0x^2 +0x^3 +6x^4 +0x^5 +0x^6 +0x^7 -9x^8
+2x^0 +0x^1 +0x^2 +0x^3 +1x^4 +0x^5 +0x^6 +0x^7 +1584935467x^8 // output of p1+p2
why is is showing 158.... in x power 8 term .
it should show simply -9x^8 only .
i am trying to learn to implement operator overloading in it .
i think the problem is in loop of overloading function .

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

class polynomial {
    int* degree ;
    int capacity ;
public:
polynomial () {
    degree = new int[5];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++){
        degree[i] = 0 ;
    }
    capacity = 5 ;
}

// copy constructor 
polynomial (const polynomial&  p){
    this -> degree = new int[p.capacity];
    for( int i = 0 ; i < p.capacity ; i++){
        this -> degree[i] = degree[i];
    }
    this -> capacity = p.capacity;

}
// assignment operator overload 
void operator=(polynomial const &p){
    this -> degree = new int[p.capacity];
    for( int i = 0 ; i < p.capacity ; i++){
        this -> degree[i] = p.degree[i];
    }
    this -> capacity = p.capacity;

}
void print(){

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < capacity ; i ++ ){
        if( degree[i] >= 0)
         cout << "+"<< degree[i] <<"x^" <<i<<" ";
        else cout<< degree[i] <<"x^" <<i << " ";
        
        
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void setCoefficient( int de , int num ){
    if( de < capacity ){
        degree[de] =  num ;
    }
    else {
        int ic = capacity ;
        capacity = capacity+(de-capacity+1) ;
        int* ne = new int[capacity];
        for( int i = 0 ; i < capacity ; i ++){
            ne[i] = 0 ;
        }
        for( int i = 0 ; i < ic; i ++){
            ne[i] = degree[i];
        }

        delete [] degree;
        degree = ne;
        
        degree[de] = num ;
    }
}

polynomial operator+( polynomial const &p){
    polynomial tp ;
    tp.capacity = max(capacity, p.capacity) ;
    int i = 0 ;
    for(; i < max(this->capacity, p.capacity) ; i ++){
        if(i <= capacity && i <= p.capacity)
        {tp.degree[i] = degree[i] + p.degree[i];}
        else if ( i < p.capacity) tp.degree[i] = p.degree[i] ;
        else tp.degree[i] = degree[i];
    }
    
    return tp;

}
polynomial operator-( polynomial const &p){
    polynomial tp ;
    tp.capacity = max(capacity, p.capacity) ;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < max(this->capacity, p.capacity) ; i ++){
        tp.degree[i] = degree[i] - p.degree[i];
    }
    return tp;

}



};

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "polynomialClass.cpp"
using namespace std;


int main (){
    polynomial p1 , p2 ;
    p1.setCoefficient(4, -5);
    p1.setCoefficient(0,+2);
    p1.print();
    p2.setCoefficient(8,-9);
    p2.setCoefficient(4,+6);
    p2.print();
    polynomial p3 = p1 + p2;
    p3.print();
    
    
}
```

Comment: The problem lies in the overloaded operators. They declare a local variable `tp`, which is allocated on the _stack_ and returned. Instead they should return a polynomial that is allocated on the heap. Variables on the stack will vanish as soon as the function that declared returns.

Comment: @Ronald It's perfectly OK to return a local variable by value. Done all the time. Consider: `int sum(int a, int b) { int result = a + b; return result;}` Would you insist that this is wrong and `result` should have been allocated on the heap instead?

Comment: `tp.capacity = max(capacity, p.capacity) ;` You increase the `capacity` member directly, but don't reallocate `degree` to match - it's still an array of 5 elements. The following loop then exhibits undefined behavior by accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik There's a big difference between returning an integer compared to an entire object. An integer (or any other native type) can be returned within a register or a register pair. This is not true for arbitrary objects.

Comment: @Ronald `std::string concat(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) { std::string result = a + b; return result; }` Do you believe there's a problem in this code, and `result` must be allocated on the heap? The function is returning an "entire object" of a class type.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks brother, you are right, now it's working